# Can druids be neutral good or neutral evil?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm playing pathfinder and it says they can be "any neutral" but I'm confused as to whether that means LN N and CN or if that also includes NG and NE.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes**

"Any Neutral" means that you need to have one of the alignment parts be Neutral. Which one doesn't matter.